# Editing commits in github

Tags: github

Using Git Bash, I just edited some commits.
In the shell it says: `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/master`

I don't see the changes in my github profile.
Do I still need to git push origin master?
I've tried this and it rejects it.

What do I need to do to finish this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `git push -f origin master`

Comment: it _f_orces your push to override the existing history.